# How to pass a Variable from Form1 to say FormN in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Hi all i want to pass the variable that has been declared in Form 1 to say FormN. Say this is my idea, there are two users anonymous user and authenticated user, who log into the ebook management system and obviously only authenticated user(AU) can edit and manipulate the database. Now i want to pass the variable say **Flag** , and will assign the flag value as 0 for anonymous user and 1 for AU.
My doubt is in form1(where i'm going to set the flag value). And how to pass this value to say Form3 so that depends upon the **Flag** i will set enable and disable the add/delete.. buttons for anonymous and Au user respectively. How to do this in VB6?

Note that the add/delete button add and delete the table in the database.

This is what i need:

In form1

```
Private Sub XXX_Click()
{
     `have to initialize the flag depending on user's log-in
}
```

in form 2, where i have to check the flag function, so that i can disable the buttons (according to user). My doubt is where to place these functions?

Comment: Have you considered a public property on `Form1`?

Comment: not importantly but i have to pass this variable so i guess it would be public.. I'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use this way:

In `Form1` you declare a public variable Flag and optionally the Form_Initialize() method:

```
Public Flag as Integer
Sub Form_Initialize()
   ' here you set your default value for this var espesially if it is not 0
   Flag = 0
End Sub
```

In `Form3` you also declare a public variable Flag:

```
Public Flag as Integer
Sub Form_Initialize()
   ' here you set your default value for this var espesially if it is not 0
   Flag = 0
End Sub
```

then in `Form1` somewhere in your code you do this:

```
Sub Your_Function()
   ' ...
   Dim f as Form3
   Set f = new Form3
   f.Flag = Me.Flag
   f.show ' or f.show vbModal
   ' ...
End Sub
```

and then in `Form3` `Form_Load()` you will have the var `Flag` already set to proper value.

Comment: sorry, in form one where i have place the code? I'm a newbie, so guide me:)

Comment: First put declaration of the variable `Flag` and then code of your functions

Answer (score 0):

We're using public variables in bas module for similar purposes. First (logon) form initializes these variables and any other forms do use them.
This approach works in simple exe file; for activex exe and dll files you should ensure that every session initializes variables for itself - public variables can live longer than user session sometimes.